# Whether the partial derivatives are bounded in any neighbourhood of $(0,0)$ or not.

Tags: derivatives, continuity, partial-derivative

The function is given as $f(x,y)=\begin{cases}(x^{2}+y^{2})\sin \left(\frac{1}{x^{2}+y^{2}}\right)& (x,y)\ne (0,0)\\0 &(x,y)=(0,0)\end{cases}$.

The options are

(a) The partial derivatives $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x},\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ exist at $(0,0)$ but are unbounded in any neighbourhood of $(0,0)$.

(b) $f$ is continuous but not differential at $(0,0)$.

(c) $f$ is differential at $(0,0)$.

(d) $f$ is continuous but not differrential at $(0,0)$

I computed the partial derivative as,

$$\begin{aligned}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\Big|_{(0,0)}&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(0+h,0)-f(0,0)}{h}\\&=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(h,0)-f(0,0)}{h}\\&=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{h^{2}\sin \frac{1}{h^{2}}-0}{h}\\&=\lim_{h\to 0} h\sin \frac{1}{h^{2}}\\&=0\end{aligned}$$

Similarly, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\Big|_{(0,0)}$ can be shown equal to 0.

Since the partial derivatives both exits and equals zero. So are continuous, hence $f$ is differential at $(0,0)$ and hence continuous too. But how to check whether the partial derivatives are bounded in any neighbourhood of zero or not?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How did you jump to "So are continuous"?

Comment: I guess you mean "differentiable", not "differential" in your question

Comment: Compute the partial derivatives at a generic point $\neq (0,0)$.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin I mean since partial derivative are zero it is continuous and since partial derivatives exists and continuous the function  is differentiable at $(0,0)$

Comment: Where did you show us that the partial derivatives are continuous?

Comment: Consider the function $$f(x,y)= \cases{ {xy\over x^2+y^2}&$(x,y) \ne (0,0)$\cr 0&$(x,y)=(0,0)$}$$ Then $f_x((0,0)) = 0 = f_y((0,0)).$ What can you conclude about the continuity of $f$ at $(0,0)$? Does the double limit $\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} f(x,y)$ even exist?

Comment: The function f is not continuous at $(0,0)$ as the limit depends on path. Hence the limit does not exist

Comment: So your conclusion is not correct. Right? Existence of partial derivatives at a point doesn't even guarantee continuity at that point; Differentiability is a far reaching thing.

Comment: Actually I thought partial derivative is coming constant, so it is continuous and since the partial derivative exists and continuous, the function $f(x,y)$ is differentiable. I think I made a mistake in concluding the continuity of partial derivative.

Comment: Every function is constant at a single point.

Comment: So here I am required to use : A function $f(x,y)$ is said to be differentiable at any point $(a,b)$ if $f(a+h,b+k)-f(a,b)=Ah+Bk+g(h,k)\sqrt{h^{2}+k^{2}}$ where $A$ and $B$ are constants independent of $h$ and $k$ and $\lim_{(h,k)\to (0,0)}g(h,k)=0$.

Comment: But I am not getting how to check whether the partial derivatives are bounded in any neighbourhood of $(0,0)$.  I was asked to calculate partial derivative at a generic point not equal to $(0,0)$. I dont know what is a  generic point. I just calculated at $(0,1)$, 
$$\begin{aligned}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\Big|_{(0,1)}&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(0+h,1)-f(0,1)}{h}\\&=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(h,1)-f(0,1)}{h}\\&=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{(h^{2}+1)\sin \frac{1}{h^{2}+1}-\sin 1}{h}\end{aligned}$$
But how should I move further, can I say as $h\to 0$, $h^{2}\to 0$  and hence $h^{2}+1\to 1$ and use it here?

Comment: Am I wrong somewhere please reply